# glTF 2.0 video texture support

Tags: three.js, 3d, gltf

I have been reading the glTF specs and looking around and haven't been able to find an explicit answer to this: are video textures supported by glTF 2.0 or one of its extensions? Could anyone point me to the right thread or documentation if such exists?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be possible with the upcoming `KHR_texture_transmission` extension. However, it is not finalized yet. Check out the following presentation for more information:

https://www.khronos.org/assets/uploads/developers/library/2018-gdc-webgl-and-gltf/glTF-Texture-Transmission-GDC_Mar18.pdf

It says on page 12:

> Video Texture formats currently in design phase

Comment: Thanks! I had seen some thread on Github about this one, but not the PDF which does refer directly to video texture support. I'll be following this closely now :)

Comment: @Silvain What's a good place to follow this for updates?

Comment: This seems recent: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/issues/1895

Comment: I've been following this, but not sure: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/issues/835